# Adding a second webapp to tomcat when context is already defined in server.xml

Tags: java, tomcat

I'm working on deploying a new webapp to run on the same server as a legacy app already running on tomcat 8.5.  The idea is to have the two apps running on same port in tomcat and be access by different contexts i.e. http://localhost:8080/oldapp & http://localhost:8080/newapp

The old app currently has its context setup in server.xml ( I know this isn't advisable, but that's how the original developer set it up and I don't want to touch it for now)

```
<Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
                   maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
                   enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
                   connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true" />
        <Connector port="8009"
                   enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" protocol="AJP/1.3" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                   resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
            <Host name="localhost" appBase="webapps"
                  unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="false" deployOnStartup="false"
                  xmlValidation="false" xmlNamespaceAware="false">
                <Context path="/oldApp" reloadable="true" docBase="applicationName"/>
            </Host>
        </Engine>
    </Service>
```

I've tried setting up a new context in catalina.home/conf/Catalina/localhost/newApp.xml

```
<!-- Context configuration file for my web application -->
<Context docBase="newApp" path="/newApp" reloadable="true">

</Context>
```

With the newApp.war placed in catalina.home/newApp/newApp.war

However when I start tomcat the newApp is completely ignored.  Can anyone advise what I need to do to get tomcat to deploy the new application?

****Edit**

Folder structure:

```
    webapps:
    total 98188
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users 58196119 Feb 15  2018 oldApp.war
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users 42226180 Sep  3 15:52 newApp.war
    drwxr-xr-x 7 tomcat users     4096 Sep  4 16:16 oldApp

    conf/Catalina/localhost:
    total 12
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users 1303 Mar 18  2013 manager.xml
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users 1148 Mar 18  2013 host-manager.xml
    -rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users  730 Sep  4 15:58 newApp.xml

webapps/oldApp/
total 40
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users   894 Jan 29  2018 favicon.ico
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users  1879 Jan 29  2018 style.css
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat users  2535 Jan 29  2018 index.html
drwxr-xr-x 5 tomcat users  4096 Sep  4 16:16 WEB-INF
drwxr-xr-x 4 tomcat users  4096 Sep  4 16:16 applicationName
drwxr-xr-x 3 tomcat users  4096 Sep  4 16:16 META-INF
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat users  4096 Sep  4 16:16 media
drwxr-xr-x 2 tomcat users 12288 Sep  4 16:16 images
```

Comment: so, in simple word, your question is "how to run two application on same port". right ?

Comment: Well no, not exactly.  Getting two applications running on same port is a case of setting up different contexts.  My question is why is the above config for the different contexts not working and tomcat only deploying the context defined in server.xml

Comment: Where are you putting the new war, in which folder?

Comment: In catalina.home/newApp folder

Comment: As you are using a relative docBase path it should be inside webapps/newApp. See https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/config/context.html docBase

Comment: If I place it in webapps/newApp.war and set newApp.xml = <Context docBase="newApp" path="/webapps" reloadable="true"> this still doesn't explode or deploy the war

Comment: why did you change the context tag? Leave it as it was. Just put the war in the webapps/newApp folder

Comment: ok - so context is reverted back to <Context docBase="newApp" path="/newApp" reloadable="true">
</Context> in webapps/ i have oldApp.war,oldApp (expolded dir) and newApp.war - is this what you meant? as its still not working

Comment: Can you add the folder structure you have under webapps to the question? Including where the war files are? You should also have a folder applicationName according to the Context tag in the question.

Comment: @Juan The question is about Tomcat 8.5, not Tomcat 5.5. Linking to Tomcat documentation that is eight years old is not useful.

Comment: @skomisa, so please explain the difference regarding the docBase

Comment: @Juan [Here is a link to the Tomcat 8.5 documentation for the Context Container](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/context.html). There are many changes in the 8.5 documentation for the Context Container  compared to the obsolete documentation you linked to.